# How do I perform a logical AND between two expressions for a prometheus alert?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have two expressions A and B and would like to create a prometheus alert such that `((A != 0) AND (B <30))`
The AND operator in PromQL performs set operations. And also the result of A and B have different labels.
I am able to perform `A!=0` and `B<30` but can't figure out the AND.

Output of A:
[image]

Output of B:
[image]

Comment: The vectors need to have the same labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Prometheus performs `and` operation individually per each pair of time series on the left and the right side of the `and` with identical set of labels according to [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

In your case the `A and B` returns nothing because `A` returns a time series with empty labelset, while `B` returns a time series with non-empty labelset, so Prometheus cannot find a pair of time series with matching labels for performing the `and` operation.

This can be fixed by using `on()` modifier, which instructs Prometheus to take into account the set of labels specified inside `on()` when searching for matching pairs of time series on the left and the right side of `and` operator. So the following query should work for your case:

```
A and on() B
```

This query specifies an empty labelset inside `on()`, so Prometheus matches any time series from `A` with any time series from `B`. See [these docs about on() modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).